# Widget object is undefined in Dashcode

Tags: widget, undefined, dashcode

I'm using Dashcode for a mobile Safari web application and from the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MakingaWidgetwithDashcode/MakingaWidgetwithDashcode.html), it appears that I should be able to access an object called "widget".

However, when I tried, I get the error message saying that widget is undefined.  I've also tried "window.widget" and it gives me the same error.

What's going on?

I'd like to make a text in my application a clickable link to open a URL using openURL (like the example given at the URL above).

Answer (score 0):

You use widget.xxx to access things inside and outside you widget. 
So to access curl and the Mac and get some data from Yahoo you do as follows

```
var yahoorate = widget.system("/usr/bin/curl 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EUR" + interim0 + "=X&f=l1'", null).outputString;
```

to get a preference key value, stored in the widgets plist when you install on a mac

```
globalPreferenceValue = widget.preferenceForKey(null, "your-key");
```

i think in the question ask (below) we are checking to see if we are in a widget and then preparing a transition to the back of the widget.

```
if (window.widget) {
    widget.prepareForTransition("ToBack");
}
```

this is how i set a preference so it is stored between system reboots (you use a get preference to retrieve them)

```
widget.setPreferenceForKey(2,"ratePrecision");
```

and this is how you create a link to open in a browser not the widget

```
<a onclick=" + "widget.openURL('http://www.wf.com/private/?ID=636');" + "><span id=company-info>click here</span></a>
```

These are all rel working examples from widgets i have built. Hope it helps. I found it useful to download widgets that performed similar functions to ones i wanted and then as well as installing them opening them as projects, you can import, and then you can see all the code.

Comment: My problem is that when I tried to use "widget.openURL...", I get a runtime error that says "Can't find variable: widget". Do I need to import some library to have access to "widget"? I'm using Dashcode 3.0.2. thanks,
Mona

Comment: Hmm i will have a look. which Mac, which OS version etc. Let me know and i will see what i can find.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this worked...hope it will help someone else...

```
window.location = "http://www.apple.com";
```